# How do I make neo4j not accessible to the world?

Tags: nosql, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm running neo4j version 1.5M01. I've also tried version 1.4.1. And I can't figure out how to stop it from running in hideously insecure mode, where anyone who connects to it over HTTP has full read/write/shell access to the database.

I know that neo4j doesn't manage security on its own. I just want to close the port so it can only be accessed from localhost.

The documentation at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-configuration.html says that this is how you *open* the port:

> Specify the client accept pattern for the webserver (default is 127.0.0.1, localhost only):
>
> `# allow any client to connect`
>
> `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0`

But if I leave that line out, it's still open. If I change it to 127.0.0.1, it's also still open.

Comment: What you mean with open? If you change the config to `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=127.0.0.1` can you create connection from other computer?

Comment: Yes. There is apparently something incorrect about the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be solved now? https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues/23

Answer (score 2):

You can block port on which neo4j runs from iptables or any routing/firewall application.
This way operating system itself will block incoming connections.
Here's command for linux:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -s \! 127.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

This command says to drop all connections to port 80 except from 127.0.0.1, just what you need.

For windows use its integrated firewall. It has a nice easy to use GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the suggestions here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/operations-security.html

Comment: The problem is that the first sentence of that page is not at all true: "Per default, the Neo4j Server is bundled with a Jetty instance that binds to host localhost on port 7474, answering only requests from the local machine."